# malloc huge chunk of data to fill ram and observe free parameters

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, malloc

I wrote a small c code snippet which allocates huge chunk of memory (say 100MB) by using malloc. Once allocated, it writes 2 bytes at beginning of each page and one byte at end of each page to ensure that physical memory is comitted. After writing it sleeps for ever making sure that memory allocated resides in RAM.

In a separate terminal, I log output of "free" command before and after running my application. I see no much change in "free" parameter in output of free command. What exactly happens when we malloc huge chunk of data. I was expecting the value of free parameter to go down an used parameter to get increased. Buts its not happening. Am I missing anything.

In short, when we malloc huge chunk at a time and write few bytes into each page allocated, will it be allocated from free Physical memory available ?

Comment: Please add to your question: the actual command-output; exactly what values you question; exactly what you expected the answer to be; and why. ### Incidentally, what you probably got for your troubles was a whole bunch of page-faults. Any OS will impose limits on the number of physical pages any process is permitted to retain, so that a *(malicious ...)* program exactly like yours *(which, BTW, I am **not** now calling "malicious!"),* could not thereby soak-up too many resources and cause denial-of-service.

Comment: @mikerobinson: on my machine, mozilla consistently uses about 20 times that much memory. But perhaps you could say it was "malicious".

Comment: Mozilla ... *koff* we need not go there ...  **;-)**

Comment: The output of `free` may be misleading. Some memory in `cached` are already free but not garbage collected. Although not garbage collected and returned to free pool, those can be immediately reused.

Comment: I gathered few stats using shell script which run in background and capture "cat /proc/meminfo" ,free,vmstat variables into files. I then plotted the data as graphs and I see that , when 400MB of memory is malloc'ed, Buffers in "cat /proc/meminfo" raises by 300MB and Cached raises by "100MB". Bit confusing. Can anyone explain please ?

Answer (score 1):

> In short, when we malloc huge chunk at a time and write few bytes into each page allocated, will it be allocated from free Physical memory available ?

If it is allocated, it will be allocated from the system's virtual memory, and any given page of the allocation may or may not be resident in physical memory at any given time.  That's how virtual memory systems work.  While your process is sleeping, memory belonging to it is a good candidate for being paged out, but it is difficult to predict whether it actually will be paged out.

Comment: The system is constantly "looking for a page to steal" when the physical-RAM resource starts to get crowded. Maybe, someone *else's* not-recently-used page will be cabbaged.  But, maybe not! When you exceed the current limit that the system has imposed for "the maximum number of resident pages that any process may now have," one of *your* pages will get stolen! (You're not allowed to grab "more than your fair share.") This limit is subject to dynamic adjustment.